# gcc: error: getting-started.c: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm very first at learning C and my gcc can't find the files

this is the file "getting-started.c"

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double A[5] = {
        [0] = 9.0,
        [1] = 2.9 ,
        [4] = 3.E+25,
        [3] =  .00007,
    };

    for (size_t i = 0 ; i<5 ; ++i) {
        printf("element %zu is %g, \tits square is %g\n",
                i,
                A[i],
                A[i]*A[i]);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

this code runs fine.
this is what I tried to do

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -lm -o getting-started getting-started.c
```

Here is my error

```
gcc: error: getting-started.c: No such file or directory
```

What should I do?
I'm working on WSL ubuntu 18.04

Comment: _this is the file "getting-started"_: As the error message is saying, it should be the file `getting-started.c`. If you haven't mistyped it in the question, it is lacking the ending `.c`.

Comment: Note that `-o file` specifies the name of the compiled executable.

Comment: Are you in the correct directory for calling gcc. Maybe try `ls`

Comment: Not related to your issue: The option `-lm` should come _after_ any module calling a function of it. Otherwise the linker will not search it for unresolved references. However, your code does not call such a function, you can as well remove this option.

Answer (score 1):

Point to your directory first where getting-started.c is placed.

For example if your file path is this:

```
C:\Users\Name\getting-started.c
```

then write in command line of your WSL:

```
 cd /mnt/c/Users/Name
```

Then run

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -lm -o getting-started getting-started.c
```